# NameError: Name 'trys1' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

In my school project I am comparing search algorithms. I don't get an error for searched numbers between 36 and 65. Above/below this number range the error occurs (NameError: name 'trys1' is not defined). I don't know why. I tried to call the def directly after the definition as it was solved for a similar question but it doesn't work. What should I do? If try1 is removed from the def diagram, the error no longer occurs.

```
import math
from Suche.SucheZahlen import Zahlen
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

index1 = []
index2 = []
index3 = []
data0 = Zahlen.data
length = len(data0) - 1


def suche(number, x, right, length, data0):
    global index1
    global trys1
    runtime = int(math.log2(length))
    for i in range(runtime + 1):
        if data0[x] <= number <= data0[right]:
            median_index = int((length + x) / 2 - 1)
            index1.append(median_index)
            if number == data0[median_index]:
                print("ja")
                trys1 = i + 1
                break
            if number - 1 > data0[median_index]:
                x = median_index + 1
            elif number - 1 < data0[median_index]:
                length = median_index + 1
            elif number - 1 == data0[median_index]:
                print("ja")
                break
        else:
            print("nein")
            break


def intervallsuche(number, right, left, data0):
    global trys2
    for i in range(right):
        if data0[left] <= number <= data0[right]:
            x = left + (number - data0[left]) / (data0[right] - data0[left]) * (right - left)
            round = x % 1
            if round < 0.5:
                x = int(x)
            if round >= 0.5:
                x = int(x) + 1
            index2.append(x)
            if data0[x] == number:
                trys2 = i + 1
                print("ja")
                break
            if data0[x] > number:
                right = right - 1
            if data0[x] < number:
                left = left + 1
        else:
            print("nein")
            break


def linearesuche(number, x, right, data0):
    global trys3
    if data0[x] <= number <= data0[right]:
        for i in range(right):
            if number == data0[x]:
                trys3 = i
                print("ja")
                break
            else:
                x = x + 1
            index3.append(x)
    else:
        print("nein")


def diagramm():
    x1 = list(range(trys1))
    x2 = list(range(trys2))
    x3 = list(range(trys3))
    x4 = [0, length]
    y1 = index1
    y2 = index2
    y3 = index3
    y4 = [number, number]
    xmin = 0
    xmax = trys3
    ymin = 0
    ymax = data0[100]
    plt.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
    plt.scatter(x1, y1)
    plt.scatter(x2, y2)
    plt.scatter(x3, y3)
    plt.plot(x4, y4)
    plt.xlabel("X")
    plt.ylabel("Y")
    plt.show()


number = int(input("number:"))
linearesuche(number, 0, length, data0)
intervallsuche(number, length, 0, data0)
suche(number, 0, length, length, data0)
diagramm()
```

Comment: Where do you think this is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, some code feedback: You should almost never use global variables for anything. It is extremely rare that you'll actually need them, and they cause all sorts of namespace problems if you aren't careful - this being an example.

The actual issue: You haven't actually created a global variable called `trys1` outside of the `suche` function. Global variables need to be defined on the global namespace, and then calling them inside the function simply tells Python that you're trying to modify that global variable, rather than a new local one.

If that's confusing, hopefully the example below will clarify. The below code will return 2, because you told the `foo` function that you're trying to modify the `c` that you defined above, not a local `c` that you created within the confines of the function.

```
c = 1
def foo():
  global c
  c = c+1
  return c

print(foo())
```

This time, the below code should give the same `NameError` that you received (although I haven't tested), because you're trying to tell the `foo` function to modify the global variable `c`, but there is no global variable `c`.

```
def foo():
  global c
  c = c+1
  return c

print(foo())
```

Now, the below code will simply modify the `c` variable inside the function.

```
def foo():
  c = 1
  c = c+1
  return c

print(foo())
```